# How to apply 2 different transformation on my dataset using pytorch

Tags: image-processing, pytorch

I am preparing my data for a downstream CNN application in pytorch. I wish to use the transform methods = ToTensor() and Resize() both on the same dataset. I am not able to apply them together.

```
from torchvision.datasets import ImageFolder
from torchvision.transforms import ToTensor # In order to convert the datat to pytorch tensors
from torchvision.transforms import Resize
```

Able to apply them separately, but need to apply both these transforms on the same dataset. The image files are stored in `"/content/sub_folder"` directory.

```
dataset = ImageFolder("/content/sub_folder" , transform = Resize([224,224])) # ToTensor is method

dataset = ImageFolder("/content/sub_folder" , transform = ToTensor()) # ToTensor is method
```

How to apply both these transformation on all the images contained in my folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you can use compose to use multiple transforms

```py
from torchvision import transforms as T
from torchvision.datasets import ImageFolder

trans_comp = T.Compose([
  T.Resize([224,224]),
  T.ToTensor()
])

dataset = ImageFolder("/content/sub_folder", transform=trans_comp)
```